# Model works but there is no graph outputed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, scikit-learn

So, I built my model and everything is working. I have an RMSE. I have the data and the axis. Yet I have no lines in my graph.

It originally worked when I did it for 2017/2018. But, now I'm doing 2018/2019. I guess I must have changed something without realizing.

The graph currently looks like this : https://gyazo.com/8448d327c952446e661c2411eb4a1405

As you see, everything is present, but there is no plot.

For the code, this is the function that I wrote that makes the graph.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

def run_model(_matrix, _target, label):
  # Run model and calculate error
  model.fit(_matrix.loc[_matrix.index.year<2019], _target.loc[_target.index.year<2019])
  error = mean_squared_error(model.predict(_matrix.loc[_matrix.index.year == 2019]), _target.loc[_target.index.year == 2019])

  # Draw plot
  plt.figure(figsize=[16,9], dpi=300)
  plt.plot(_matrix.index, _target, _matrix.index, model.predict(_matrix), linewidth=1)
  plt.xlim(left=mdate.datestr2num("2018-04-15"), right=mdate.datestr2num("2019-10-31"))
  top=200
  plt.ylim(bottom=0, top=top)

  # Add info
  try:
    text_str = "Intercept: {:.1f}".format(model.intercept_)
    for i, row in enumerate(pd.Series(model.coef_, index=_matrix.columns).iteritems()):
      text_str += "\n{}: {:.1f}".format(row[0], row[1])  
  except:
    text_str = ""

  plt.text(
    x=mdate.datestr2num("2019-10-31"),
    y=top-6,
    s=text_str,
    bbox=dict(facecolor='gray', alpha=0.2),
    verticalalignment='top',
    horizontalalignment='right'
  )
  plt.annotate(
    label,
    xy=(mdate.datestr2num("2018-04-15"), top-10),
    fontsize=18,
    fontweight='heavy'
  )
  plt.annotate(
    "RMSE = {:.2f}".format(math.sqrt(error)),
    xy=(mdate.datestr2num("2019-04-05"), top-10),
    fontsize=14,
  )
  plt.annotate(
    "Training",
    xy=(mdate.datestr2num("2018-04-15"), 3),
    fontsize=10,
  )
  plt.annotate(
    "Testing",
    xy=(mdate.datestr2num("2019-04-15"), 3),
    fontsize=10,
  )

  rect = Rectangle((mdate.datestr2num("2018-04-15"), 0), 365, 200, facecolor="black", alpha=0.05)
  plt.gca().add_patch(rect)

  plt.show()
```

Comment: The code works. I'm just confused as to why I have no graph.

Comment: Might be something wrong with your `plt.xlim` or `plt.ylim` settings. Do you see anything plotted if you comment out those lines?

Comment: @Randy something does plot in this case. But, I wanted 2019 alone. By removing them, it gives me 2014 to 2019 and removes the text values that I need (RMSE on the graph, etc.). For context, with those lines it looks like this : https://gyazo.com/8448d327c952446e661c2411eb4a1405 & without it looks like this : https://gyazo.com/bbe9d515367bb0873ba4c537cb95ed81

Comment: It looks like it's your `plt.ylim` then - compare the scales of the Y axis on your first and second plots.