# Model works but graph is empty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, scikit-learn

So, my teammate [posted this already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61981515/model-works-but-there-is-no-graph-outputed) and got no response.

---

We built a model.

Our model and numbers work. We have the title and the axis as well. But the graph is empty. Originally, when the RMSE wasn't as good, we had a graph.

So, I assume that I must have changed something without realizing. We probably ran the notebook with the fix and I somehow didn't realize it and deleted the fix.

For context for the current dilemma, the graph looks like this right now : https://gyazo.com/8448d327c952446e661c2411eb4a1405

As for function for making the graph it is the following :

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

def run_model(_matrix, _target, label):
  """
  Take features_matrix and target_df and run it through whatever the current model is.
  Plot results.
  """

  # Run model and calculate error
  model.fit(_matrix.loc[_matrix.index.year<2019], _target.loc[_target.index.year<2019])
  error = mean_squared_error(model.predict(_matrix.loc[_matrix.index.year == 2019]), _target.loc[_target.index.year == 2019])

  # Draw plot
  plt.figure(figsize=[21,12], dpi=300)
  plt.plot(_matrix.index, _target, _matrix.index, model.predict(_matrix), linewidth=1)
  plt.xlim(left=mdate.datestr2num("2018-04-15"), right=mdate.datestr2num("2019-10-31"))
  top=200
  plt.ylim(bottom=0, top=top)

  # Add info
  try:
    text_str = "Intercept: {:.1f}".format(model.intercept_)
    for i, row in enumerate(pd.Series(model.coef_, index=_matrix.columns).iteritems()):
      text_str += "\n{}: {:.1f}".format(row[0], row[1])  
  except:
    text_str = ""

  plt.text(
    x=mdate.datestr2num("2019-10-31"),
    y=top-6,
    s=text_str,
    bbox=dict(facecolor='gray', alpha=0.2),
    verticalalignment='top',
    horizontalalignment='right'
  )
  plt.annotate(
    label,
    xy=(mdate.datestr2num("2018-04-15"), top-10),
    fontsize=18,
    fontweight='heavy'
  )
  plt.annotate(
    "RMSE = {:.2f}".format(math.sqrt(error)),
    xy=(mdate.datestr2num("2019-04-05"), top-10),
    fontsize=14,
  )
  plt.annotate(
    "Training",
    xy=(mdate.datestr2num("2018-04-15"), 3),
    fontsize=10,
  )
  plt.annotate(
    "Testing",
    xy=(mdate.datestr2num("2019-04-15"), 3),
    fontsize=10,
  )

  rect = Rectangle((mdate.datestr2num("2018-04-15"), 0), 365, 200, facecolor="black", alpha=0.05)
  plt.gca().add_patch(rect)

  plt.show()
```

---

One fix that I tried is to remove the  `plt.xlim` & `plt.ylim` parts to see if it plotted something. It did plot something but all the text/annotations was/were needed got removed : https://gyazo.com/bbe9d515367bb0873ba4c537cb95ed81

So, we're lost as to what to do to get something plotted. We know it should work, since it did at some point.

---

Furthermore, what is especially weird is that earlier in the notebook, this graphs perfect :

```
from matplotlib import dates as mdate
plt.figure(figsize=[21,9], dpi=300)
plt.plot(feature_matrix.index, target_df, feature_matrix.index, model.predict(feature_matrix))
plt.xlim(left=mdate.datestr2num("2019-04-15"), right=mdate.datestr2num("2019-10-31"))
plt.show()
```

It's the same syntax or am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO; please notice that, in general, getting no answer in ~ 8 hours after posting is no justification for re-posting the same question. In any case where re-posting is deemed necessary, you should include a link to the previous question (added).

Comment: Thank you for the heads up on that. I didn't know.